# Problems using getline

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working on my final project for my intro to c++ class, and I had an issue with my code.  getline does not seem to be working, although I typed it exactly as I have many other times and have seen elsewhere.  Here is the section of code in question

```
    if (groceryMenu == 2)
        {
            string groceryItem;

            system("CLS");

            cout << "Enter what you would like to add to the grocery list: " << endl;
            getline(cin, groceryItem);

            groceryVector.push_back(groceryItem);
```

When this is run, the cout line shows on screen (it just flashes, but with a system("PAUSE") after you can see it stays), but then it exits the if loop and returns to the main loops.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated :)

Here is the rest of my code, if that helps.  I know it is rough; I just started on it.

```
// 7.3 lists and vectors
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int menuInput = 0;
    int exitProgram = 0;
    vector<string> groceryVector;
    vector<string> hardwareVector;
    vector<string> choreVector;
    fstream inputFile, outputFile;

    string groceryInput;
    inputFile.open("grocery.txt");

    while (getline(inputFile, groceryInput))
    {
        groceryVector.push_back(groceryInput);
    }
    inputFile.close();

    string hardwareInput;
    inputFile.open("hardware.txt");

    while (getline(inputFile, hardwareInput))
    {
        hardwareVector.push_back(hardwareInput);
    }
    inputFile.close();

    string choreInput;
    inputFile.open("chore.txt");

    while (getline(inputFile, choreInput))
    {
        choreVector.push_back(choreInput);
    }
    inputFile.close();

    while (exitProgram == 0)
    {
        system("CLS");

        cout << "List Manager" << endl;
        cout << "Press 1 to manage the grocery list." << endl;
        cout << "Press 2 to manage the hardware store list." << endl;
        cout << "Press 3 to manage the chore list." << endl;
        cout << "Press 4 to exit." << endl;

        cin >> menuInput;

        if (menuInput == 4)
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Now exiting program." << endl;
            exitProgram = 2;
            break;
        }

        while (menuInput == 1)
        {
            system("CLS");

            int groceryMenu = 0;

            cout << "Press 1 to read the grocery list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 2 to add an item to the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 3 to delete an item from the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 4 to return to the main menu." << endl;

            cin >> groceryMenu;

            if (groceryMenu == 1)
            {
                system("CLS");

                for (string groceryList : groceryVector)
                {
                    cout << groceryList << endl;
                }

                system("PAUSE");
            }

            if (groceryMenu == 2)
            {
                string groceryItem;

                system("CLS");

                cout << "Enter what you would like to add to the grocery list: " << endl;
                getline(cin, groceryItem);

                groceryVector.push_back(groceryItem);

            }

            if (groceryMenu == 3)
            {
                int eraseLine = 0;

                system("CLS");
                cout << "What line would you like to erase from the list?" << endl;
                cin >> eraseLine;

                groceryVector.erase(groceryVector.begin() + (eraseLine - 1));
            }

            outputFile.open("grocery.txt");

            for (string groceryList : groceryVector)
            {
                outputFile << groceryList << endl;
            }
            outputFile.close();

            if (groceryMenu == 4)
            {
                menuInput = 0;
            }
        }

        while (menuInput == 2)
        {
            system("CLS");

            int hardwareMenu = 0;

            cout << "Press 1 to read the hardware list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 2 to add an item to the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 3 to delete an item from the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 4 to return to the main menu." << endl;

            cin >> hardwareMenu;

            if (hardwareMenu == 1)
            {
                system("CLS");

                for (string hardwareList : hardwareVector)
                {
                    cout << hardwareList << endl;
                }

                system("PAUSE");
            }

            if (hardwareMenu == 2)
            {
                string hardwareItem;

                system("CLS");

                cout << "Enter what you would like to add to the hardware list: " << endl;
                getline(cin, hardwareItem);

                hardwareVector.push_back(hardwareItem);
            }

            if (hardwareMenu == 3)
            {
                int eraseLine = 0;

                system("CLS");
                cout << "What line would you like to erase from the list?" << endl;
                cin >> eraseLine;

                hardwareVector.erase(hardwareVector.begin() + (eraseLine - 1));
            }

            outputFile.open("hardware.txt");

            for (string hardwareList : hardwareVector)
            {
                outputFile << hardwareList << endl;
            }
            outputFile.close();

            if (hardwareMenu == 4)
            {
                menuInput = 0;
            }
        }

        while (menuInput == 3)
        {
            system("CLS");

            int choreMenu = 0;

            cout << "Press 1 to read the chore list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 2 to add an item to the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 3 to delete an item from the list." << endl;
            cout << "Press 4 to return to the main menu." << endl;

            cin >> choreMenu;

            if (choreMenu == 1)
            {
                system("CLS");

                for (string choreList : choreVector)
                {
                    cout << choreList << endl;
                }

                system("PAUSE");
            }

            if (choreMenu == 2)
            {
                string choreItem;

                system("CLS");

                cout << "Enter what you would like to add to the chore list: " << endl;
                getline(cin, choreItem);

                choreVector.push_back(choreItem);
            }

            if (choreMenu == 3)
            {
                int eraseLine = 0;

                system("CLS");
                cout << "What line would you like to erase from the list?" << endl;
                cin >> eraseLine;

                choreVector.erase(choreVector.begin() + (eraseLine - 1));
            }

            outputFile.open("chore.txt");

            for (string choreList : choreVector)
            {
                outputFile << choreList << endl;
            }
            outputFile.close();

            if (choreMenu == 4)
            {
                menuInput = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do `cin >> menuInput` this simply reads in your menuInput number but keeps the new line `\n` still in the buffer. When you call `getline` it will return you empty line because there was a `\n` still waiting. When you mix `getline` you should clear input buffer before you use `getline`:

```
cout << "Enter what you would like to add to the grocery list: " << endl;
cin.ignore(); // <<== you need this!
getline(cin, groceryItem);
```

You'll need to add that to each of your `getline` calls that read from `std::cin`.
This should fix your problem.

Other than that, some suggestions:

- don't use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`, try to remove it, but then your console wouldn't clear.
- refactor your code into separate functions, do not stuff everything into `main()`. For example, after `cin >> menuInput` based on `menuInput` you can call one of the functions: `manageGroceries(...)`, `manageHardware(...)`, `manageChores(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. your problem description is poor so I will be guessing
2. The biggest problem is that you put everything in `main` function. Split it to smaller functions, this way lots of code can be reused and final code will be 3 times smaller. Note "grocery", "hardware" and "chore" are doing same thing. The only differences are cosmetic and can be parametrized.
3. Do not use `system("cls")` it is widows specific and doesn't do what you are expecting (it only give such feeling). This is result of not understanding what is the difference between standard input/output and console.

I'm guessing that you have enter invalid value to the input what changed state of the standard input to state where it is unable to read data.

Use `cin.clear()` to clear error state on input and `cin.synch()` to clean up (ignore) all data waiting in console buffer, so next read operation on `cin` will read data freshly provided into console.